# PostgreSQL conditional statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement

I need to implement a conditional `SELECT` statement based on the result
of another statement. I don't want to create a function for this purpose, but simply using conditional `SELECT`.

My unsuccessful approach looks as below:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
IF SELECT count(*) FROM table1 < 1 THEN
   SELECT * FROM table2;
   RETURN QUERY;

ELSE 
   SELECT * FROM table3;
   RETURN QUERY;
END IF;
END
$do$
```

I could accomplish the same result by checking the results of my query in PHP
and based on this, perform another query, yet I'm wondering if it's possible to do this solely in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @NickBarnes I edited the post: first query has to count results and based on that another query has to return results. All queries in my particular case are quite long, so I decided to replace them with simpler equivalent. If you ask about columns, all 3 queries will have the same columns

Comment: `return query` is a **single** statement. It should be `return query select ...` - but a PL/pgSQL block can't return anything so you can't use `return query` in there anyway

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good point, is there any possible way to make PL/pgSQL return a query?

Comment: You can make a PL/PgSQL _function_ return something, but not an anonymous block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
with c as (select count(*) cnt from table1)
select table2.* from table2, c where c.cnt < 1
union all
select table3.* from table3, c where c.cnt >= 1
```

Comment: In a general case if you want to know if a query does not exists is better NOT EXISTS than COUNT (*) < 1

Comment: Yes. If the condition is only about existence (like in the question) then `EXISTS` is certainly preferable.

Comment: @acesargl using `with` is preferred when you want to use a `SELECT` multiple times, you can also use `with` in your answer ;).

Comment: Using count you force to count all the tuples, using NOT EXISTS when one tuple is found the inner SELECT is aborted (EXISTS and NOT EXISTS usually use short-circuit or McCarthy evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

If table2 and table3 are union-compatible then you can use a single SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1)
UNION
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1);
```

Comment: As a performance issue use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` ;).

Comment: I also suggest you to use `SELECT 1 FROM table1` instead of `SELECT * FROM table1` ;).

Comment: Exists and not exists ignore the projection list in the nested select. So, in this case, select * and select 1 are equivalent.